# Please change all occurrences of "import gobject" to "from gi.repository import GObject"

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, gtk, gobject

I try to improt Gtk like this: 
`from gi.repository import Gtk`

and I get the following error:

`ImportError: When using gi.repository you must not import static modules like "gobject". Please change all occurrences of "import gobject" to "from gi.repository import GObject"`

And I get the same error when I try `from gi.repository import GObject`

Help me to solve this problem, please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reinstalled `python-gobject` and `python-gobject-2`, and now everything is working!